# How to place a card and form right next to each other using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Below is my code.  Trying to get a Card to sit next to my Form (form in middle) and then another card on the right (3 items all in a line.)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://www.abbasees.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/MORTGAGE-ADVISER.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Fill in the fields in the form to the right to find out your fixed-rate mortgage.  This type of mortgage is sometimes referred to as a "Vanilla Wafer"
                    and the interest rate remains the same throughout the entire life of the loan.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="https://psujohnny03.github.io/Portfolio/">Back to Portfolio</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<form action="">
    <div class="space">
        <label>APR%:
            <input type="text" id="apr" name="APR" />
        </label>
        <label>Loan Term (Years):
            <input type="text" id="trm" name="APR" />
        </label>
        <label>Loan Amount:
            <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" />
        </label>
        <label>Down Payment:
            <input type="text" id="dpmt" name="dpmt" />
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="pmt" name="mPmt" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
            <input type="button" id="sbt" value="Calculate" />
        </a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
            <input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form" />
        </a>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://www.abbasees.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/MORTGAGE-ADVISER.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Fill in the fields in the form to the right to find out your fixed-rate mortgage.  This type of mortgage is sometimes referred to as a "Vanilla Wafer"
                    and the interest rate remains the same throughout the entire life of the loan.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="https://psujohnny03.github.io/Portfolio/">Back to Portfolio</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding this so I can post because for some reason the site brings up an error saying I need to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

This will work you Fine.

```html
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="http://www.abbasees.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/MORTGAGE-ADVISER.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>Fill in the fields in the form to the right to find out your fixed-rate mortgage. This type of mortgage is sometimes referred to as a "Vanilla Wafer" and the interest rate remains the same throughout the entire life of the loan.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="https://psujohnny03.github.io/Portfolio/">Back to Portfolio</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form action="" style="float:left;width:50%">
  <div class="space">
    <div><label>APR%:</label>
      <input type="text" id="apr" name="APR" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Loan Term (Years):</label>
      <input type="text" id="trm" name="APR" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Loan Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Down Payment:</label>
      <input type="text" id="dpmt" name="dpmt" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="pmt" name="mPmt" />
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
      <input type="button" id="sbt" value="Calculate" />
    </a>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
      <input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form" />
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  My goal is to have a card on the left, form in middle, and another card on the right.  Although this code helped it shrunk the size of my card and threw it all the way left and took my form and threw it all the way right, instead of center.  Maybe I should have included another card in my code to explain in it's entirety.  I will paste my new code below.  The layout is fine but my cards have become very skinny.

Comment: @psujohnny03 add the extra code to your original question as an edit, so we can see it better. By the way what do you mean by card?

Comment: Ok, adding code now.  When I say card I am referring to the cards you can use from a site called MaterializeCSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `display:flex;` to `wrap` div.**

Learn about `flex`:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://www.abbasees.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/MORTGAGE-ADVISER.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Fill in the fields in the form to the right to find out your fixed-rate mortgage.  This type of mortgage is sometimes referred to as a "Vanilla Wafer"
                    and the interest rate remains the same throughout the entire life of the loan.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="https://psujohnny03.github.io/Portfolio/">Back to Portfolio</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<form action="">
    <div class="space">
        <label>APR%:
            <input type="text" id="apr" name="APR" />
        </label>
        <label>Loan Term (Years):
            <input type="text" id="trm" name="APR" />
        </label>
        <label>Loan Amount:
            <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" />
        </label>
        <label>Down Payment:
            <input type="text" id="dpmt" name="dpmt" />
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="pmt" name="mPmt" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
            <input type="button" id="sbt" value="Calculate" />
        </a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
            <input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form" />
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: But `flex` only gives you support after **IE11** - https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @weBBer the OP didn't mantion that he needs it to IE....

Comment: That I know, just added this for his information as you should have in my opinion. :)